# From a set, retrieving ALL fields of an external Hash

Tags: redis, socket.io

So far I have only been able to retrieve a single hash field for each element in a set. Is there a direct or indirect way to retrieve ALL hash values AND fields for each element in a set? I do not know all the keys in the hash, so multiple GET commands after the SORT command will not work.

This is what I have working:

#### sort user:100:venuePointers BY nosort GET user:100:venues:*->name

I am looking for something like this:

#### sort user:100:venuePointers BY nosort HGETALL user:100:venues:*->*

Answer (score 1):

With the current Redis version (2.6.14) it's not possible do to this with just one command.

What you can do is get all the values of your list then iterate calling HGETALL for each value:

```
LRANGE user:100:venuePointers 0 -1

for each value:
    HGETALL hashKey
```

Comment: And be sure to use pipelining to execute the successive HGETALL commands.